# Asking A Colleague for a Letter of Recommendation

Tags: job, supervision, independent-researcher, lecture-teaching-method, professorship

I am working as an Assistant Professor at a university for over 2 years, but I am not happy with my current job and university. I want to apply to a university in another country (from where I've done my PhD) for a faculty position.

I'd like to know if it would help the application if a colleague who is a PhD and already holding a Tenure Track Position writes a letter of recommendation for in support of this application?

Comment: To be sure I understand correctly, the colleague is a more senior colleague at the place you are currently working at or they are at the place you apply to?

Comment: To explain more, yes, he knows me for over 2 and a half year, but he is working with me at my current place of working, not at the place I am applying to

Answer (score 5):

In a comment, you noted that this individual is working with you at your current position.

Yes, I think you should have a letter from a colleague at your current institution. Indeed, if you *didn't* have a letter from a co-worker (ideally, your chair, but I know that's tough for assistants) it would raise red flags. This letter should speak to your expertise in research, teaching, and service *but* almost more importantly, provide some context as to why you are departing. Search committees will want to have a narrative that you're moving to another university because it's better or for some other germane reason, and *not* because you're being forced out or are a toxic colleague, if that makes sense.

So not only should you have a letter from a colleague at your current university, I would argue that it's almost always a necessity.